# Making a bow shoot more than one arrow at once

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I make a bow that shoots 5 arrows with 1 shot?
In general, how can I make a bow that shoots more arrows in a single shot than the normal bow?

Comment: Until minecraft comes out with that multi-shot enchantment, it would be impossible unless you cheat by summoning four arrows when the bow is shot.

Comment: Is this in a creative or survival scenario ?

Comment: @SpiceWeasel Well, crossbows have that.

Comment: @Alfons What did you try so far? Where exactly are you stuck? What did you research? … We're here to help you on specific problems, not to do your project complete for you.

Comment: @Fabian will it not also work for bows? Now I think I've been lied to :P

Comment: @SpiceWeasel No, it doesn't. I just wanted to be nitpicky.

Comment: It's a minigame map in the 1.12 and a kit shut be able to shot with 1 bow 3 arrows and I tried and tried but I can't did it...

Answer (score 0):

well if you're using vanilla minecraft you'l need to use scoreboard and testfore commands to detect when a player rightclicks a bow and it will add a tag wich activates a chain of commandsblocsk that summon Arrows and add custom tags for them to be able to move them seperatly and make a shooting animation wich is a so hard and i don't Think you'll use it

but if you're on a multiplayer server you can basicily use CE plugin to add the Custom enchant *Multiarrow*